# Object.assign required modules?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to combine `Object.assign` with `require` for module import / export. Example use case:

```
// foo/bar.js
module.exports = () => console.log('foo')
```

```
// foo/biz.js
module.exports = Object.assign({}, require('./bar')
```

With the above, the object exported from `biz.js` is always empty. Yet to my eye it looks like it should contain the function exported from `bar`. Could someone ELI5 why it does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> module.exports = () => console.log('foo')

You are exporting a function! Not an object with a key. You can try these ways:

Way 1:

```
// foo/bar.js
module.exports = () => console.log('foo')

// foo/biz.js
module.exports = Object.assign({}, {bar: require('./bar'})
```

Way 2:

```
// foo/bar.js
module.exports = {
   bar: () => console.log('foo')
}

// foo/biz.js
module.exports = Object.assign({}, require('./bar')
```